# Как создать эффект перемещения <tr> по таблице?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть таблица, некий "топ" пользователей обновляющийся раз в пару секунд. Каким образом возможно сделать так чтобы ряды (`<tr>`) плавно менялись местами? И возможно ли это вообще?
Сейчас (может важно) занимает таблица меньше 50% страницы, она находится в выпадающем блоке справа.
Вот html

```html
<table id='topInvest' border-collapse='1'>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Место</th><th>Игрок</th><th>Очки</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>USERNAME</td>
    <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>dd301d31</td>
    <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Czcz33</td>
    <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Username1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>ff404</td>
    <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Если важно, в css реализован эффект "скролла" таблицы с помощью Вот этого css кода

````css
table {display: block; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }
thead, tbody{
    width: 100%;
}

thead th {
    position: sticky;
}

tbody {
    height: 40vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    width: 100%;
}
tr{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1rem 0;
}
th, td{
    flex: 33%;
}```
````

Comment: Возможно. Покажите вашу разметку.

Comment: Поменял, добавил, простите за задержку

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Держите пример, но не стоит считать его как единственно возможный + я не делал никаких проверок на введенные значения и тд.

Для изменения положения меняйте числа в блоках.

```js
function sort(items) {
  items.sort((a, b) => (+b.innerText) - (+a.innerText))
}

function setPositions(items) {
  items.forEach((item, i) => item.style.setProperty('--pos', i))
}

function getItemHeight(item) {
  return item.getBoundingClientRect().height
}

function setParentHeight(parent, itemHeight, n) {
  parent.style.setProperty('--height', itemHeight * n + 'px')
}

function update(items) {
  sort(items)
  setPositions(items)
}

let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')]
items.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('input', () => update(items)))

setParentHeight(
  document.querySelector('.table'),
  getItemHeight(items[0]),
  items.length
)

update(items)
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table {
  position: relative;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: var(--height);
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  
  background-color: lightblue;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--pos) * 100%));
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(.95, -0.54, .52, .75);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="item" contenteditable>1</div>
  <div class="item" contenteditable>1</div>
  <div class="item" contenteditable>1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Для моего случая как нельзя лучше подошло